Inconsistent behavior and poor performance on Squid web filter
I've been trying to use the Squid proxy server program for a while now as a filter to block access to "problem" websites on my browsing computers such as social media sites, but I've never been able to adequately configure it to something satisfactory, as it always seems oddly flaky and/or inconsistent.
The current configuration is as follows. I am using a tiny computer - NanoPi R5C, like a Raspberry Pi but even smaller - which has a Debian install to host the program, set up as a gateway connecting to the Internet via its inbuilt WiFi and then to the browsing computers via ethernet. It operates in transparent proxy mode, to try and maximize compatibility with as much client software as possible.
Yet the filtering behavior seems to suffer from 2 main problems: one is that it seems inconsistent - particularly I am trying to block out Instagram, but it still seems to be able to go there on the browser sometimes. In addition to this, it is also very, very slow to connect to other sites that are not listed as blocked, potentially causing timeout errors with impatient software.
(There's also a 3rd but less important problem - though maybe related to these - which is that when trying to access a blocked site the refusal behavior feels inconsistent, e.g.
I've followed a number of tutorials and read the documentation on the basic commands but still don't know what exactly is wrong - also I note many of them seem to talk more about using it in a "whitelisting" configuration, when what I'm trying to do is use it in a "blacklisting" configuration. The config below was cobbled together as a result of that and based off tweaking the stock config. For what it's worth I'm also using a self-compiled version 6.11 to enable the necessary SSL Bump facility because all those sites use HTTPS:
# Squid configuration file

# Define the necessary variables
http_port 8080
http_port 3128 intercept
https_port 3129 intercept ssl-bump cert=/opt/etc/squid/ssl/squid.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_ce$
https_port 3130 intercept ssl-bump cert=/opt/etc/squid/ssl/squid.pem generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_ce$

# Define the cache and log directories
#cache_dir ufs /opt/var/spool/squid 10000 16 256
#cache_access_log /opt/var/log/squid/access.log
#cache_log /opt/var/log/squid/cache.log
#cache_store_log /opt/var/log/squid/store.log

# Access controls
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16  # Adjust according to your network
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80    # http
acl Safe_ports port 443   # https
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # Unregistered ports
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

# Access controls for blocked websites
acl bad_url dstdomain "/opt/etc/bad-sites.acl"
acl refuse_ssl ssl::server_name "/opt/etc/bad-sites.acl"

# SSL Bump related access
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3
ssl_bump peek step1 all

# Allow local network access
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# Block access to bad sites
http_access allow !bad_url

# Allow access to safe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than SSL_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# SSL Bump settings
ssl_bump peek step2 !refuse_ssl
ssl_bump splice step3 !refuse_ssl
ssl_bump terminate step2 all

# Finally, deny all other requests
http_access deny all

# Certificate settings for SSL Bump
sslcrtd_program /opt/libexec/security_file_certgen -s /opt/var/lib/squid/ssl_db -M 4MB
sslproxy_cert_error deny all
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
#sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER

# Log settings
access_log /opt/var/log/squid/access.log squid
visible_hostname squid.proxy

# Other optional settings
#maximum_object_size 50 MB
#memory_replacement_policy lru
#cache_replacement_policy lru

dns_v4_first on

and then the blacklist in "bad-sites.acl" is pretty straightforward:
.instagram.com
.facebook.com
.tiktok.com
.x.com
.twitter.com
.threads.net

What is going on here? I note that an awful lot of the tutorials out there seem to be several years old so I'm suspecting something may be out of date compared to the more recent Squid versions which I am using now.
